# Bash script - make all files in Directory hidden

Tags: bash, file, glob, hidden, dotfiles

I'm using the following script to make all files in a directory hidden by adding a dot "." at the beginning.

```
GLOBIGNORE=".:.."
for file in *; do
     mv -n "$file" ".$file";
done
```

How can I exclude the already hidden files?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wildcard already doesn't match any hidden files, unless you have separately enabled `dotglob`.

If you have configured `dotglob` to include hidden files, you can momentarily turn it off with

```
shopt -u dotglob
```

Using `GLOBIGNORE` enables `dotglob` so maybe the simplest fix is to take that out. You could also change it to

```
GLOBIGNORE='.*'
```

but this is effectively the same as unsetting it.